# Symbolic links for windows installation?

Tags: install4j

In install4j version up to 7.0.1 an action exists to create symbolic links on unix systems. For windows we wrote a customized action executing the command `mklink /D <link> <target>`. Maybe it could be an improvement to integrate this to the symbolic link action for windows, too?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have added this to our issue tracker.